# What does "平穏とは消耗を以て代わりに成す" mean?

Tags: meaning, translation

This is a sentence from a song called "ロウワー", but I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean. The wiki translation says it's "Tranquility is exchanged for attribution" but that seems a bit too different from the original phrase. If that is indeed the correct translation though I'd like to ask why it means that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Aを以て【もって】Bとなす"** is a fairly archaic-sounding, or [kanbun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun)-style, construction meaning "to regard A as B". For example, the first sentence of the [Seventeen-article Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeen-article_constitution) says 以和爲貴, or 和を以て貴しとなす ("Regard harmony/peace as being precious.").

Thus, 平穏とは消耗を以て代わりに成す means "as for 平穏, one regards 消耗 as an alternative", or "消耗 can be regarded as a replacement of 平穏". (に is being used instead of と, but in this context it doesn't matter much.) In other words, the sentence is saying (in a very roundabout and pompous manner) that 平穏 ("tranquility; peacefulness; calmness") and 消耗 ("exhaustion; dissipation") are effectively synonymous to the speaker. Simply put, "(my) being quiet means being tired" or "I am quiet because I am exhausted". After reading the [entire lyrics](https://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/nulut/lower/), you can see the person in the song is so disappointed and tired that he has lost the will to say things loudly (or take any proactive action whatsoever).

Answer (score 3):

今回あなたが訪ねている

> 平穏とは消耗を以て代わりに成す

と言うのは直訳するとあなたが翻訳したような文章になっていますが、確かに英語にしてみると少し変です。

なぜならこの表現の仕方が日常単語などではあまり無く、どちらかというとこの様な「vocaloid」の歌詞などでよく使われる独特な表現方法です。

ほとんどのボーカロイドにはストーリーや何かしらの意味があり、こういう歌詞もその設定上でその物語や出来事を語っている、もしくは説明しているときによく使われます。

この「ロウワー」が表現しているストーリーなどからこの歌詞の意味を推測してみましょう。

おそらくいくつかの既存の考察から推測する限り「平穏とは消耗を以て代わりに成す」の意味はここでは、「平穏」は心を「消耗」した先にあるもの…と歌っているようです。

つまり、「平穏」と言うのは心を消耗しないと（減らさないと）得ることができない物だよ、と言う意味です。

前後の歌詞を見てみても、おそらくこういった意味が正しいかと思われます。

> まだ誰も知らない感覚で救われていく
> 平穏とは消耗を以て代わりに成す
> 実際はどうも変わりはなく
> 享楽とは嘘で成る
> 「綻ぶ前にここを出ていこうか」と....

Comment: "代わりに" の部分を無視して、「平穏とは消耗を以て成す」つまり「平穏とは消耗を通じて達成するものだ」のように解釈されている気がします。文字通り読めば「平穏とは消耗を言い替え(だと見做し)たものだ」の方が近いのでは、と思うのですが如何でしょう。

Comment: @naruto なるほど！！！これを呼んだ時に思わず納得して声が出てしまいました。　すごくわかりやすいコメントです。私が意味の取り違え方を少し勘違いしていたようです。申し訳ございません。この回答は消去したほうが良いでしょうか？

Comment: とりあえず消さなくていいとは思います…自分も100%自信があるわけではありませんし。ただ、歌詞はここからさらに何かを得るため消耗する人の歌ではなく、既に消耗して諦めて逃げ去りたい人の歌であるように感じました（最後に少し希望が見えますが）。

Comment: @naruto なるほど。ものすごいわかりやすい考察です。わかりやすすぎて鳥肌立ちました。笑 　確かにそうですね、言われてみればそんな感じがします！